# openid or saml for single signon with service providers

Tags: openid-connect, openid, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am not able to find a solution after doing research for more than 2 day on this, hence trying to get my understanding right in this platform.

As far as I know, we use SAML2.0 for Single signon to integrate with third party apps via the assertions. These apps are called `service providers` who count on `IDP` for authentication and gets back an `assertions`.

Various links on the internet also mentions that OpenID connect can be used instead of SAML for single singon where the applications redirect the user to the `IDP` and get the user authenticated.

OpenID is built on top of OAuth2 server and solves the authentication concern and OAuth2.0 for Authorization concern.

1. Can `OpenID` be used for single sign On with third party applications?
2. In case `yes`, should the third party application which is a Service Provider support OpenID explicitly.
3. In my current scenario, the third party application is supporting SAML and is itself a OAuth2.0 compliant. So, should it explicitly also work as a OIDC?
4. To give you an example, Office 365 can act as a SP for integrating with my IDP but can Office 365 can also work with my IDP with OpenID

Please help me if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, when you say OpenID you mean OpenID Connect?

In general, any IDP that supports SAML and OIDC will allow SAML or OIDC clients (SP) to authenticate against it and get a token.

The client has to support one of these protocols to be able to connect.

It is rare for a client to support both (why would you - it's more work?)

So:

- 1 = Yes
- 2 = Yes
- 3 = Maybe. Does it support OIDC? You mention OAuth. They are not the same
- 4 = O365 sits on top of Azure AD, Azure AD supports both SAML and OIDC

Comment: I meant OpenID Connect. By the way is there any difference between OpenID and OpenID connect?

Comment: Yes OpenID is older and I doubt if there's much support any more.

Comment: In my case, I am using Keycloak as my IDP and it supports both `OpenID Connect` and `SAML`

Comment: Just to be clear, If the IDP supports SAML and OpenID connect, the SP or the relaying party should also be supporting OIDC to leverage OIDC based authentication right. In my case I see only the documentation for SAML and not OICD. Hence, I assume  that SAML is the only way out. Please let me know if I am correct.

Comment: SAML works really well for server-side applications, But SAML was simply not designed for modern application types, such as SPAs and mobile apps. Instead of fighting the protocol, it is recommended to use OAuth 2.0 and OIDC for these application types.